# assigning values by operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++

I tries the below code, but I'm getting infinite loop that is infinite number  of values in the output
may I know the reason and what my mistake is:
I'm getting the values to enter
but after entering I'm getting  infinite number of zeroes
may the problem be solved:
the below one is the code:

```
   #include<iostream>
   class Vector
   {
       int n,*a,i;
       public:
       Vector()
       {
           int n;
           int *a;
       }
       Vector(int n)
       {
           a=new int[n];
           std::cout<<"Enter array elements "<<std::endl;
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               std::cin>>a[i];
           }
           std::cout<<"the elements od the vector are: "<<std::endl;
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               std::cout<<a[i]<<std::endl;
           }
       }
       Vector(Vector &v)
       {
           a=v.a;
           std::cout<<"using Copy Constructor elements are:"<<std::endl;
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               std::cout<<a[i]<<std::endl;
           }
       }
       Vector& operator=(const Vector& v)
       {
           int n=v.n;
           a=v.a;
           std::cout<<"after assigning values are:"<<std::endl;
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               std::cout<<a[i]<<std::endl;
           }
           delete []a;
           return *this;
       }
       ~Vector()
       {
           std::cout<<"Destructor called"<<std::endl;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       Vector v1(4);
       Vector v2(v1);
       Vector v3;
       v3=v1;
   }
```

Comment: Your copy constructor and assignment operator are broken.  What you have there does not take care of properly copying `Vector` objects.  You also failed to deallocate the memory in the `Vector` destructor.

Comment: Please go through some C++ books. You have used the Constructors incorrect way. Like defining variables, other than memory allocation code etc. Find some good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: thankyou  for your explaination

Answer (score 1):

Your `Vector` constructor is not updating the member `n` at all, so it's uninitialized when used, for example, in the copy constructor.

You need to do something like this:

```
Vector(int n) : n(n) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Also, your copy constructor, and assignment operator are incorrect. In both cases, you are not allocating memory for the `a` pointer, and even if you did, in you're deleting `a` in your assignment operator before returning.

---

Also, your default constructor does nothing useful:

```
Vector()
       {
           int n;
           int *a;
       }
```

You can just remove it, or do `Vector() = default` if that's suitable for you. In that case, you should initialize `a` and `n` inside the class.

Comment: Not to mention even if the code were allocating memory for the `a` pointer, `operator=` immediately calls `delete[] a;` on the receiving vector.

Comment: @NathanPierson True, added.